# In ember todos example, how do I extend the todo view?

Tags: ember.js

Busy learning ember.js using the todos example code. I'm messing around with templates and views. I want to extend the default view to the todo controller, but I can't figure out the name.

the posts view is Posts.PostsView
the posts/index view is PostsIndexView

but post is not PostView?!?

What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, to display the todo list you have the following code in the template:

```
{{#each filteredTodos itemController="todo"}}
    ...
{{/each}}
```

The way `{{#each}}` works is that it creates a virtual view for each item so there is no automagically named view that you can extend. However, it is possible to supply your own view class by changing it like so:

```
{{#each filteredTodos itemController="todo" itemViewClass="App.TodoView"}}
```

Then you just need to define the view class that you referenced and you're ready to go!

Comment: I'm using the standard routes as part of the todos demo code on github, find it here [link](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/emberjs/js/router.js). Maybe that's my problem, I need to add a new route!?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you are actually asking. Are you trying to create a custom view for each individual todo in the list?

Comment: yes, that's it. (still learning, so I'm confused myself here)

Comment: I've updated the answer to match what you're asking. Hope it helps!